# Jssor - How to display multiple thumbnail navigator on the same container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jssor

I have been playing with the api of jssor for a little while now and there is a setup that I can't manage to reproduce.

I am trying to use a nested slider (http://www.jssor.com/demos/nested-slider.html)

but display the thumbnails for the set of slides that is being displayed. After looking at the api code, the library doesn't seem to allow multiple thumbnail navigator on the same slide container (apparently the slides set selectors in the nested sliders counts as a thumbnail navigator).

I have tried setting thumbnail navigators with unique id for each of the sub sliders containers but that gave me weird results.

Basically, I would like to merge the nested slider and this one http://www.jssor.com/demos/image-gallery-with-vertical-thumbnail.html so that the vertical thumbnail navigator shows me the current set of slides.

Is it possible to do that?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow steps below to work it out.

1. make a main slider with thumbnail
2. make child sliders with thumbnail
3. place each child slider in each slide of main slider.

Btw
Please let me know the thumbnail skin for main slider, and the thumbnail skin for child slider, I will work out a demo for you.

---

please check out the demo http://www.jssor.com/testcase/nested-slider-with-thumbnail.source.html

Comment: For the main slider I would like http://www.jssor.com/demos/list-slider.html but displayed at the left of the container if possible and for the child slider I would like this skin http://www.jssor.com/demos/image-gallery.html

thanks a lot!

Comment: please check out the demo http://www.jssor.com/testcase/nested-slider-with-thumbnail.source.html